# WordPress: How to include & symbol in an escaped url

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to include a stylesheet in my theme:

```
wp_enqueue_style('colors-css', '/root/assets/css/colors.css?style=blue');
```

The problem is, WordPress escapes this, and adds a version number onto the end. So, instead of having this:

```
/root/assets/css/colors.css?style=blue&ver=3.9
```

I end up with this:

```
/root/assets/css/colors.css?style=blue&#038;ver=3.9
```

What do I do to correct this so the URL is rendered correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the output that you're seeing is in your HTML, then it is correct.  `&` is a reserved entity and can be encoded as `&amp;` or `&#038;`.

The browser will never send `&#038;` in the URL for the request.  It will be interpreted as `&`, as you intended.